# Unit testing directive's controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am struggling to get the controller from within a directive for unit testing. Here is my angular app:

```
angular.module('test-app', [])

    .controller('loadingCtr', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    }])

    .directive('loading', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            controller: 'loadingCtr'
       };
    });
```

Here is my unit test code:

```
describe('loading', function () {

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {

        var fooElement = $compile('<loading></loading>')($rootScope);
        var fooController = fooElement.controller('loading');

        $rootScope.$digest();
        console.log(fooController);
    })); 

    describe('loading: testing loading directive', function() {
        it('should create loading directive', function() {
        });
    });
});
```

Here is a plnkr to mess around with: http://plnkr.co/edit/38cc5HQFgeHDhnC8OMo8?p=info

fooController always returns as undefined. I've tried using the following examples I've found online, but I always get the same results:

[Unit testing a directive that defines a controller in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624315/unit-testing-a-directive-that-defines-a-controller-in-angularjs)

http://daginge.com/technology/2014/03/03/testing-angular-directive-controllers-with-jasmine-and-karma/

Is there something obvious here that I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only issue i can see is that you are not loading the module `test-app` in your fixture, which means that the compiled html code does not really compile the directive `loading` since it is not available in the injector. So try loading the module in the `beforeEach` block. Loading the module ensures that directives, controllers, services etc registered under the module is available in the injector otherwise it will just use the module as `ng` which does not know anything about the `loading` directive.

i.e

```
describe('loading', function () {
   var fooController;

    //Load the module 
    beforeEach(module('test-app'));

    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $compile) {

        var fooElement = $compile('<loading></loading>')($rootScope);
        fooController = fooElement.controller('loading');

        $rootScope.$digest();
        console.log(fooController);
    })); 

    describe('loading: testing loading directive', function() {
        it('should create loading directive', function() {
          expect(fooController).toBeDefined();
        });
    });
});
```

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/pramodsankarl/pen/epKNqV?editors=101)**

Also note that if you are registering the controller with `.controller` you can directly get the controller instance by `$controller(ctrlName)` construct. If you are using `controllerAs` syntax with `bindToController:true` in your directive then you can get it from the scope with the property name same as the alias as well.