# How to test controller in a directive?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

```js
angular.module('myModule', ['somedeps'])
  .directive('myAwesomeDirective', myAwesomeDirectiveFn)


function myAwesomeDirectiveFn() {
  function myAwesomeDirectiveCtrl (someDeps) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.variable_x, vm.variable_y;
    
    vm.action_a = function action_a() {
      console.log("Yaaa, I am action a");
    }
  },
    
  function myAwesomeLinker(scope, element, attribute, controller) {
    //Just print something on console
    element.on('click', function () {
      controller.action_a();
    });
  }
  
  return {
    restrict : 'AE',
    scope : {
      x : '=',
      y : '='
    },
    controller : myAwesomeDirectiveCtrl,
    controllerAs : 'vm',
    link : myAwesomeLinker,
    templateUrl : 'someTemplate.html'
  }
}
```

Now I want to write a unit test to test my directive and controller inside it.

I get the directive by doing following

```
directiveElement = angular.element('<my-awesome-directive x = "x" y = "y" />');
var vm = $rootScope.$new();
vm.x = 10;
vm.y = 20;

directiveElement = $compile(directiveElement)(vm);
vm.$digest();
```

My understanding was that I can get the controller by doing following

```
controller = directiveElement.controller('myAwesomeDirective');
```

but controlller is still undefined.

What am I doing wrong or is this completely wrong? I want to encapsulate my directive with controller. I do not want to create any controller on module.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unit testing a directive that defines a controller in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624315/unit-testing-a-directive-that-defines-a-controller-in-angularjs)

Comment: Hey.  What was your solution to this?  I need to do exactly this, but the answer below doesn't work for me and you have not indicated that that was the correct answer.  How did you solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just write

```
$compile(directiveElement)(vm);
```

and don't assign the result to `directiveElement`.

See also the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624315/unit-testing-a-directive-that-defines-a-controller-in-angularjs) on stackoverflow.